# How to specify number of digits to print from a table using babel?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, r

New to org/babel, so forgive me if this doesn't make sense. I have some code (in R) that produces a table. I also specify (in R) the number of digits that I want with `options(digits = 2)`. When I run the code to produce the table in R, everything works well. However, when I do `C-c C-c` on the source block, it inserts results with many digits. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :exports results :colnames yes
  options(digits = 2)
  thedata <- data.frame(
    a = runif(100),
    b = runif(100))

  library(dplyr)

  thedata %>%
    summarize(meana = mean(a), meanb = mean(b))

#+END_SRC
```

Comment: I can't replicate your results with many digits. Can you include `options("scipen")` within the R code block and confirm the value ? Your R session is temporary. What happens if you add `:session *R*` options to `#+BEGIN_SRC R` , to include **.Rprofile** settings from your directory ?